# How do I access the second item in this Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is probably really simple but I have a statement...

```
console.log($scope.data);
```

And in the console window I see...

```
[pension: "123", postcode: "GL"]
```

I have two questions...

1. What type of object is this?
2. How do I get access to the value (rather than the key) with a for
   loop?

I tried...

```
for (item in $scope.data) {
    console.log(item[1]);
}
```

But all I get is...

```
e
o
```

Not I cannot use the 'pension' or 'postcode' I need to be able to iterate the collection.

I was thinking I would need to use JSON.parse? But this seems like an overkill, because I originally instantiated $scope.data as an array. So why cant I access it like an array?

Comment: that doesn't look like a javascript object.

Comment: That's an odd object. Is it only displayed array-like because it has a `.length`, is it an actual array unintentionally, or is it something else with a unnormal stringification?

Comment: You need to ensure the data is being returned in the correct JSON format from the server (i.e. the request being made before your console.log()). This doesn't look valid.

Comment: I did $scope.data.pension = jsonFromServer.pension, is this a problem?, because it seems to bind okay to angular html elements...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just how `for..in` loops work. The keys are assigned to `item` one by one, and then you use `$scope.data[item]` to get the value of that particular key.

Comment: In case it wasn't obvious; I wanted to elaborate that the first Index of an Array in JavaScript is 0; not 1.  The reason @exitos gets e, and o from the loop in the original question is that e is the second letter of pension (AKA index=1) and o is the second letter of postecode ()AKA Index=1).